# The way to send duplicate email to the user?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made simple email in wordpress but it would only send email to the administrator email. I need to find the way to send duplicate email with Thanks to the user.

```
    $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
    if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
        $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
    }
    $subject = 'I Have A Question to Ask from '.$name;
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nComments: $comments";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;


    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

    }
```

Insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Great way to spam people, since there is no validation that the email they provide is really theirs.

Comment: @dragon - it is rather long code. So I pasted the code that I only need to know how to send duplicate email.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - erm, I have validation that checks for the email address (preg_match), but now I think about it, you have a point. There is no way to check for the email address whether it belongs to them?

Comment: No, there is no possible way to check whether the person entering an email address in a form is entering their own email address or the address of somebody they want to spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you already have the user's email address in `$email`, right? you used it in the message you showed in the question.

```
$subject = '(duplicate) I Have A Question to Ask from '.$name;
$body = "This message was sent to the administrator:\n\nName: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nComments: $comments";
$headers = 'From: '.$name.' ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
wp_mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: ah thanks! so I need to re-use wp_mail() for sending duplicated emails to users.

Comment: you use it to send one message, you can use it to send another.

Comment: ok, but if i use one message to user, but not to admin user. So i have to use wp_mail() twice. right?

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
wp_mail($email, "Thank you for your message", $body, $headers);
```